# Mail Flow Rule Predicates - AND clause in exceptions?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, office365

I am administering our mail flow rules on Microsoft Office 365 Exchange Admin.

I currently have a functional basic mail flow rule. For example:

- If the sender has domain xyz@abc
- Mark spam confidence at 8
- Except if IP range is x.xxx.xxx.xxx

Great, no trouble, working fine.

What I'd like is to apply a stricter exception. For example:

- If the sender has domain xyz@abc
- Mark spam confidence at 8
- Except if IP range is x.xxx.xxx.xxx
- **AND Except if recipient is in the list xyz-managers**

From what I can tell, this is not possible. The only option I can find is to allow exceptions linked by OR rather than AND.

Is there any way to directly or indirectly achieve this logic? It seems strange that it would be unavailable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment, you can create two rules and that can allow exceptions linked by AND rather than OR. Here are two screenshots in my environment for your reference.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How about your issue? Did my solution work?